# Different ways of computing list length in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, clp, clpz

Here are 4 different ways of computing list length in Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpz)).

list_length1([], 0).
list_length1([_|T], N) :-
    N #> 0,
    N1 #= N - 1,
    list_length1(T, N1).


list_length2(A, N) :-
    N #>= 0,
    list_length2(A, 0, N).

list_length2([], N, N).
list_length2([_|T], I, N) :-
    I #< N,
    I1 #= I + 1,
    list_length2(T, I1, N).


list_length3(A, N) :-
    list_length3(A, 0, N).

list_length3([], N, N).
list_length3([_|T], I, N) :-
    I1 is I + 1,
    list_length3(T, I1, N).


list_length4([], 0).
list_length4([_|T], N) :-
    list_length4(T, N0),
    N is N0 + 1.
```

- `list_length1` - mathematically straightforward, works in all directions
- `list_length2` - not sure what is this good for, created by analogy
- `list_length3` - last call optimized, works in one direction only
- `list_length4` - recursive, works in one direction

Is there any merit to `list_length2` or `list_length4`?

Comment: list_length3 and list_length4 appear to work in all directions, in SWI Prolog. i.e. `list_length4([1,2,3], 3)` and `list_length4([1,2,3], Len)` and `list_length4(Ls, 3)` and `list_length4(Ls, Len)` all do reasonable things up to the first solution found, at least?

Comment: Consider:  `?- N=1+0,list_length1([0],N).` which succeeds, yet, `?- list_length1([0],N),N=1+0.` fails. So why is this *mathematically straightforward*?

Comment: @false, what I meant with that is that it's the most direct translation of `len([A|T]) = 1 + len(T)`.

Comment: https://ridgeworks.github.io/clpBNR/CLP_BNR_Guide/CLP_BNR_Guide.html implies that a CLP version of `list_length` can be useful, depending on circumstances.

Comment: There isn't any merit to any of those; the built-in length/2 covers it all. You really need to explain better the _need_ for any of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `list_length2` - not sure what is this good for, created by analogy

To better understand the difference between version 1 and 2, consider a **generalization** of the predicate. A gross generalization. Simply add the facts `list_length1(_,_).` and `list_length2(_, _, _).` in front of their definitions. Now from a declarative viewpoint, these definitions get useless. But from a procedural viewpoint we now get some useful hints:

```
?- list_length1("abc",N).
   true
;  clpz:(_A+1#=N), clpz:(N in 1..sup), clpz:(_A in 0..sup)
;  clpz:(_A+1#=N), clpz:(_B+1#=_A), clpz:(N in 2..sup), clpz:(_A in 1..sup), clpz:(_B in 0..sup)
;  clpz:(_A+1#=N), clpz:(_B+1#=_A), clpz:(_C+1#=_B), clpz:(N in 3..sup), clpz:(_A in 2..sup), clpz:(_B in 1..sup), clpz:(_C in 0..sup)
;  N = 3.
?- list_length2("abc",N).
   clpz:(N in 0..sup)
;  clpz:(N in 1..sup)
;  clpz:(N in 2..sup)
;  clpz:(N in 3..sup)
;  N = 3.
```

So, version 1 has to create a chain of trivial arithmetical relations and their accompanied variables proportional to the length of the list that will get updated by each further inference and that will get collapsed in the very last moment, whereas version 2 is happy with a single domain (which in this case is infinite) that gets more and more constrained by each step.

(The operations related to `I` are effectively all trivial `(is)/2`-computations.)

Try `?- list_length2(L,N), N = 10000.` to see the difference performance-wise.

In theory, version 1 could kind of avoid the creation of these trivial relations and update a single variable avoiding the intermediary variables, but so far I have not seen a system capable of doing this. And even if there would be such a system, version 1 would still be slower than version 2 which is just happy with a single variable.

> Is there any merit to `list_length4`?

This version produces answers in a very costly, unnecessarily quadratic manner. For each further answer of `list_length4(L, N)` it needs time proportional to the length of `L`. Try, e.g. `?- list_length3(L,N), N = 10000.` and compare it to version 4.

And for the mathematical straightforwardness, please consider to use `(#)/1` in your programs. So in stead of `N #>= 0` just write `#N #>= 0`.

Comment: is there documentation on what `(#)/1` does exactly?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/blob/607c84a79ba38326693617255ed692b1625d5f70/src/lib/clpz.pl#L892).

Comment: Even documented in [SWI](https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html#sec:A.9.13).

Comment: ... which misses `op(150, fx, #)` for better readability.